# How to import DynamoDB table into PySpark?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

With JSON Line I can do at [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark):

```
  schema_table = StructType([
      StructField('created_at', TimestampType(), True),
      StructField('id', StringType(), True),
      StructField('matches', ArrayType(
          StructType([
              StructField('code',StringType(),True),
              StructField('prefix',StringType(),True),
              StructField('price',DoubleType(),True),
          ]),True)
      ,True),
  ])
  table = spark.read.json('s3://my-bucket/my-dynamodb-table', schema_table)
```

How to perform with a source at a DynamoDB table?